# Wrong display of VAT

Tags: magento2, price, vat

**Magento version 2.2.6**

I have a problem with the addition of a product price and a selected attribute (or more) price(s)

In this shop I have entered the prices 'excluding VAT'.

The product page is displayed correctly.
However, once I select an option, the VAT attribute is added to the product price excluding VAT.

This is not correct.
See example; the total sum must be 1185 euros.

[image]

**Any suggestion or help will be appreciated**